# NotificationCenter with EKEventStoreChanged notification called multiple times with different notifications

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

First of all please note that I am not registered multiple times as observer as described in various other questions.

When I change something in the native calendar application and return back to my app the selector gets called 4-5 times with different notifications.

In `viewDidLoad` I remove any possible observers and register agian once:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadModelData(notification:)), name: Notification.Name.EKEventStoreChanged, object: nil)
```

The corresponding method:

```
@objc private func reloadModelData(notification: NSNotification) {
    debugPrint("method called \(notification)")
}
```

Leads to this output

> "method called NSConcreteNotification 0x170246300 {name = EKEventStoreChangedNotification; object = ; userInfo = {\n    EKEventStoreChangedObjectIDsUserInfoKey =     (\n        \"x-apple-eventkit:///Location/p259707\",\n        \"x-apple-eventkit:///Event/p264955\"\n    );\n}}"
>   "method called NSConcreteNotification 0x174258840 {name = EKEventStoreChangedNotification; object = ; userInfo = {\n    EKEventStoreChangedObjectIDsUserInfoKey =     (\n        \"x-apple-eventkit:///Location/p259707\",\n        \"x-apple-eventkit:///Event/p264955\"\n    );\n}}"
>   "method called NSConcreteNotification 0x17024b250 {name = EKEventStoreChangedNotification; object = ; userInfo = {\n    EKEventStoreChangedObjectIDsUserInfoKey =     (\n        \"x-apple-eventkit:///Location/p259707\",\n        \"x-apple-eventkit:///Event/p264955\"\n    );\n}}"
>   "method called NSConcreteNotification 0x174253b00 {name = EKEventStoreChangedNotification; object = ; userInfo = {\n    EKEventStoreChangedObjectIDsUserInfoKey =     (\n        \"x-apple-eventkit:///Location/p259707\",\n        \"x-apple-eventkit:///Event/p264955\"\n    );\n}}"

Does anyone know how fix this. Meaning only receiving one single call of this observer when re-entering the app?

Comment: Please state a problem you are having. When you ask for suggestions, it's not clear what you mean by that.

Comment: I edited the question accordingly

Comment: Did you find a solution? II have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this is how it works, the calendar sends you notifications for all primitive changes you've made.

[The Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1507525-ekeventstorechanged) suggests to check reminders and events you're accessing by calling `refresh`. If it returns `true`, there's no need to refetch them. So multiple notifications arriving wouldn't cause much of a problem.

Also I would recommend to subscribe for notifications in `viewWillAppear(_:)` and unsubscribe in `viewDidDisappear(_:)`. Of course there might be exceptions, but usually you don't want to handle them when the screen is not active.

Comment: According to the docs it is also ok to refetch all events and reminders - which is what I will be doing.

There are also 4-5 calls even if I simply delete one single event. This should not trigger so many observer actions in my opinion.

Comment: @ph1lb4 then what's the problem?

Comment: @ph1lb4 try to `removeObserver` in `viewDidDisappear` and add in `viewWillAppear`. Also in view will appear you'll have to check if anything has been changed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately I already tried that. The problem is not that I am subscribed multiple times to the observer as the notification is different each time. The problem is that there are several notifications when only one should be triggered.

Comment: @ph1lb4 I didn't say that you're subscribed multiple times. I said that you should be subscribed only when a view controller is visible.

Comment: Ok sorry for the misunderstanding. However the problem is that when you switch from an app to another app `viewDidDisappear` is not called. Therefore I cannot unsubscribe in just the right moment.